# Cellular Automaton Not Woorking

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life, agent-based-modeling, mason-abm

Update: Just to specify, depending on how I change the rules I can set it so within a couple of generations all cells are either permanently alive or dead. I have checked this by echoing statements to console. HOWEVER, this doesn't reflect in the GUI which shows all cells as always the same color.

I am trying to implement a simple Cellular Automaton to replicate the game of life. This uses the MASON library. My three classes:

Cell.java

```
package sim.app.gol;

import sim.engine.SimState;
import sim.engine.Steppable;
import sim.field.grid.IntGrid2D;
import sim.util.IntBag;

public class Cell implements Steppable {

    public IntGrid2D grid = new IntGrid2D(0,0);

    public void step(SimState state) {

        Matrix matrix = (Matrix) state;

        grid.setTo(matrix.matrix);

        for(int x = 0; x < grid.getWidth(); x++) {

            for(int y = 0; y < grid.getHeight(); y++) {

                IntBag nei = grid.getMooreNeighbors(x, y, 2, 0, false, new IntBag(), new IntBag(), new IntBag());

                int count = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < nei.size(); i++) {

                    count += nei.get(i);

                }

                int currentState = grid.get(x, y);

                if(currentState == 0) {

                    if(count > 3)
                        matrix.matrix.set(x, y, 1);


                } else if(currentState == 1) {

                    matrix.matrix.set(x,y,0);


                }

            }


        }




    }

}
```

Matrix.java

```
package sim.app.gol;

import ec.util.MersenneTwisterFast;
import sim.engine.SimState;
import sim.field.grid.IntGrid2D;

public class Matrix extends SimState {

    public final int HEIGHT = 10;
    public final int WIDTH = 10;
    public IntGrid2D matrix = new IntGrid2D(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    public final int NUM_CELLS = 80;

    public Matrix(long seed) {

        super(seed);

    }

    public void start() {

        super.start();

        // Utils for random number generator
        MersenneTwisterFast g = new MersenneTwisterFast();

        // We set everything to 0, no cells are active
        matrix.setTo(0);

        // Populating
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CELLS; i++) {

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            // We don't want to mark as 'active' a cell that is already active
            do {
                x = g.nextInt(WIDTH);
                y = g.nextInt(HEIGHT);
            } while(matrix.get(x, y) == 1);

            matrix.set(x, y, 1);


        }

        schedule.scheduleRepeating(new Cell());


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        doLoop(Matrix.class, args);
        System.exit(0);

    }



}
```

MatrixWithUI.java

```
package sim.app.gol;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import sim.app.students.Students;
import sim.display.Console;
import sim.display.Controller;
import sim.display.Display2D;
import sim.display.GUIState;
import sim.engine.SimState;
import sim.portrayal.continuous.ContinuousPortrayal2D;
import sim.portrayal.grid.ObjectGridPortrayal2D;
import sim.portrayal.grid.ValueGridPortrayal2D;
import sim.portrayal.simple.OvalPortrayal2D;

public class MatrixWithUI extends GUIState {

    public Display2D display;
    public JFrame displayFrame;
    public ValueGridPortrayal2D matrixPortrayal = new ValueGridPortrayal2D();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MatrixWithUI mwu = new MatrixWithUI();
        Console c = new Console(mwu);
        c.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void start() {

        super.start();
        setupPortrayals();

    }

    public void load(SimState state) {

        super.load(state);
        setupPortrayals();

    }

    public void setupPortrayals() {

        Matrix matrix = (Matrix) state;
        matrixPortrayal.setField(matrix.matrix);
        matrixPortrayal.setPortrayalForAll(new OvalPortrayal2D());

        display.reset();
        display.setBackdrop(Color.white);

        display.repaint();

    }

    public void init(Controller c) {

        super.init(c);
        display = new Display2D(600,600,this);
        display.setClipping(true);

        displayFrame = display.createFrame();
        displayFrame.setTitle("Schoolyard Display");
        c.registerFrame(displayFrame);
        displayFrame.setVisible(true);
        display.attach(matrixPortrayal, "Yard");

    }

    public void quit() {

        super.quit();
        if (displayFrame != null) displayFrame.dispose();
        displayFrame = null;
        display = null;

    }

    public MatrixWithUI() { 

        super(new Matrix (System.currentTimeMillis())); 

    }

    public MatrixWithUI(SimState state) {

        super(state);

    }

    public static String getName() {

        return "Student Schoolyard Cliques";

    }

}
```

However, for some reason all cells are continuously set to 0 (or off). Any thoughts?

Comment: My suggestion would be to step through the code in a debugger and/or add print statements at strategic points, to see where exactly things are going wrong.

Comment: Your rules are not Conway's rules. They seem to be rules that would lead the whole matrix to die within a couple of generations or so. Is that what's happening?

Comment: @NPE that's the thing, when I echo statements cells turn on and off as appropriate but the changes are reflected in the GUI. But I can't understand where I've gone wrong in that.

Comment: @max0005: That last comment should be right at the top of your question. :)

Comment: @NPE uh apologies, I'll fix :)

Comment: Well, what about using the correct rules? As NPE has correctly pointed out...

Comment: Your oval doesn't have anything that tells it to draw a different color for a different cell value. You should probably override its `draw` method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think that's it but I don't understand particularly well how that class works. Could you help by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this is a tentative answer as I have no way of verifying it at the moment.

First, let's look at the [documentation of `ValueGridPortrayal2D`](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/docs/classdocs/sim/portrayal/grid/ValueGridPortrayal2D.html). It says:

> Like other `FieldPortrayal2D`s, this class uses an underlying `SimplePortrayal2D` to draw each separate element in the grid. A default `SimplePortrayal2D` is provided which draws squares. In the default, the color for the square is determined by looking up the value of the square in a user-provided color-table, or if there is none, by interpolating it between two user-provided colors. See the `setColorTable()` and `setLevels()` methods.

So, if you settle for squares rather than ovals, you can drop this line:

```
    matrixPortrayal.setPortrayalForAll(new OvalPortrayal2D());
```

And instead, add:

```
    java.awt.Color[] colorTable = new java.awt.Color[2];
    colorTable[0] = new java.awt.Color(1.0F,0.0F,0.0F,0.0F);
    colorTable[1] = new java.awt.Color(1.0F,0.0F,0.0F,1.0F);
    matrixPortrayal.setMap( new SimpleColorMap(colorTable) );
```

This should give you white squares (transparent on a white backdrop) for `0`, and red squares for `1`.

If you want to draw ovals, this default implementation of a `SimplePortrayal2D` that uses a map is not available. The documentation goes further to say:

> You can also provide your own custom `SimplePortrayal2D` (use `setPortrayalForAll(...)` ) to draw elements as you see fit rather than as rectangles. Your `SimplePortrayal2D` should expect objects passed to its draw method to be of type `MutableDouble`.

So we need to override the `draw()` method and treat the passed object - the cell value - as a `MutableDouble` (by which I assume they mean the one from `org.apache.commons.lang`):

```
    matrixPortrayal.setPortrayalForAll(new OvalPortrayal2D() {
        public void draw(Object object, Graphics2D graphics, DrawInfo2D info) {
            MutableDouble valueObj = (MutableDouble)object;
            if ( valueObj.intValue() == 0 ) {
                paint = new java.awt.Color(1.0F,0.0F,0.0F,0.0F);
            } else {
                paint = new java.awt.Color(1.0F,0.0F,0.0F,1.0F);
            }
            filled = true;
            super.draw(object, graphics, info);
        }

    });
```

So we have created an anonymous subclass of `OvalPortrayal2D`. It inherits the fields `paint`, `filled` and `scale` from `AbstractShapePortrayal2D`. So we override paint (`java.awt.Paint`, which `java.awt.Color` extends) with the color we need for the particular value, and make sure the oval is filled.

Comment: Hi @RealSkeptic, thanks. Hm, I'm afraid I don't have a constructur for Color taking four doubles, I've changed it to ints which seems to work? Also, all I get is a blue background :\

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? There is a four-float constructor in Java 7 for sure. If you are using the four `int` constructor, you should be using `255` instead of `1.0`.

Comment: I have JRE7 on Eclipse but get an error on  colorTable[0] = new java.awt.Color(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0); telling me the constructor is undefined

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Since they are floats, they should be `1.0F` and `0.0F` rather than `1.0` and `0.0`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Also, I assume that the second element of the array should begin with a ( instead of a [?

Comment: Hm, Graphics2D and Info2D cannot be resolved to type nor is it suggesting anywhere to import from :\

Comment: `java.awt.Graphics2D` and `sim.portrayal.DrawInfo2D`. And yes, I have corrected the bracket. BTW, my two suggestions are mutually exclusive - either you do the default (with color table) or the ovals.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! :D I'll have to look through properly and better understand the GUI, but in the meantime thanks so much :3